# Nyquist plot of $1/[s(s+1)(s+2)(s+3)]$

Tags: transfer-function, nyquist

I am trying to learn how to plot by hand Nyquist plots.
I took
$$G(s) = \frac{1}{s(s+1)(s+2)(s+3)}$$
I converted it to $G(jw)$ :
$$G(jw) = \frac{i w (-11 + w^2)}{(1 + w^2) (4 + w^2) (9 + w^2)} + \frac{6 - 6 w^2}{36 + 49 w^2 + 14 w^4 + w^6}$$

Now when I am computing the points that cut the axes we have:
$$Re(G(jw))=0 \implies w=1$$
$$Im(G(jw))=0 \implies w=0 \text{ or } w=\sqrt{11}$$

Also, $$\lim_{w \rightarrow +\infty}(Re(G(jw)) = -\infty$$

That means that the Nyquist plot should look something like :
[image]

But matlab printed this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You missed an extra element in MATLAB while doing this. I think your defined your transfer function as:

```
H = tf(1,[1 6 11 6]);
Nyquist(H)
```

which gives you this diagaram:

[image]

You should have defined the tf as

```
H = tf(1,[1 6 11 6 0]);
Nyquist(H)
```

As you can see, the second code gives you the correct result:

[image]